# Qlik Sense Set Analysis (A or B) and (C or D)

Tags: qliksense

Trying to write a function to pull counts for Items sold in (Region A or Region B) AND (Region C or Region D). An intersection between these 2 sets

```
count({<Item={'Region A', 'Region B'} * {'Region C', 'Region D'}>} Item)
```

This is not working.
Example:

```
[O,R,S]
[O1,A,10]
[O2,B,20]
[O2,D,20]
[O1,C,10]
[O3,A,25]
[O4,B,35]
```

Expected result:
Only count: O1 since it was sold in region A and C and O2 since it was sold in region B and D. Do not count O3, O4

Final count would be 2

Comment: Can you also try this? `count({ (<Order={'Region A'}> + <Order={'Region B'}>) * (<Order={'Region C'}> + <Order={'Region D'}>) >} Orders)`

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
=count({<Order={'Region A', 'Region B'}>} Orders)
 +
 count({<Order={'Region C', 'Region D'}>} Orders)
```

That way you are just adding results of both.

Comment: zedfoxus I don't think this will work for me, as it unions counts from first set with second. I can only count if at least one of the conditions from both sets is satisfied. So I can only count if an the same order is in Region A AND Region C or Region A AND Region D or Region B AND Region C, or Region B and Region D. thanks.

Comment: Gotcha. Can you add some sample data and expected results to your question? You might get better traction my posting it to Qlik community

Comment: Updated the question with an example for completeness sake. will try the posting to Qlik community

Answer (score 0):

Asked the same question on the Qlik community site and got a correct answer:

```
Sum(
    Aggr(
        Count({<Region = {'A', 'B'}>} Region) *
        Count({<Region = {'C', 'D'}>} Region),
        Item
    )
)
```